# how to create codeigniter url to human friendly url?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

my projects is almost done.but i just need a Seo friendly url for my projects
my current url is

```
http://localhost/example/product/category/1
```

I want to convert this url into this

```
http://localhost/example/product/category/name-of-category
```

pls help guys

Comment: Please download Human friendly codeigniter :P

Comment: you can use `routing`  for more help check http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use something like slug

```
public function category($slug)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('slug' => $slug), 1);

    // Fetch the post row, display the post view, etc...
}
```

Use dashes to separate words

```
 $slug = url_title($title, 'dash', true);
```

you need to take care for this slug to be unique :)